# Reading parquet files in Databricks from Azure Data Lake results in java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: pyspark, databricks, parquet, azure-eventhub, azure-data-lake

We have an Azure Databricks Notebook that is reading parquet data files from our "RAW" folder that has been streamed from Azure Eventhub into Azure Data Lake in Parquet format and partitioned on Year/Month/Date, where a folder for one day can contain 10.000+ parquet files from 20 KB to 6 MB.

Example file path: `RAW/ConsumptionData/Parquet/V1/CapturedYear=2023/CapturedMonth=10/CapturedDay=30/137341728_872c9ee8bbaf4c58b8ee7a401f459b41_1.parquet`

This has been working fine for some time but now it has begun to crash due to issues with

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

So we need to adjust something, either in the code or the partitioning or the cluster specs.

The notebook is built up with the following basic statements:

```
# Read the data with a defined schema
consFromRAW = ( spark
    .read
    .option("header","True")
    .schema(schema)
    .parquet( "/mnt/datalakegen2/RAW/ConsumptionData/Parquet/V1")
)
```

Even though Spark is lazy and should not execute anything on this statement it takes forever and is now endning in memory errors and does not reach the next statement where we do the filtering:

```
# Filter the exact date partitions needed
consFromRAWFiltered = consFromRAW.filter(col("CapturedDate") >= firstRAWReadDate)
```

where firstRAWReadDate is usually NOW() minus 2 days and CaptureDate is a date made by concatenation of folders CapturedYear, CapturedMonth and CapturedDay.

Some details on the cluster:

Driver: Standard_DS3_v2
Workers: Standard_DS3_v2
2-16 workers
10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)

```
Error details:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3957504232682417> in <module>
     72 
     73     # Read the data with the defined schema
---> 74     consFromRAW = ( spark
     75         .read
     76         .option("header","True")

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in parquet(self, *paths, **options)
    299                        int96RebaseMode=int96RebaseMode)
    300 
--> 301         return self._df(self._jreader.parquet(_to_seq(self._spark._sc, paths)))
    302 
    303     def text(self, paths, wholetext=False, lineSep=None, pathGlobFilter=None,

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o533.parquet.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.resize(HashTable.scala:258)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.addEntry0(HashTable.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.findOrAddEntry(HashTable.scala:170)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.findOrAddEntry$(HashTable.scala:167)
    at scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet.findOrAddEntry(LinkedHashSet.scala:44)
    at scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet.add(LinkedHashSet.scala:68)
    at scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet.$plus$eq(LinkedHashSet.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet.$plus$eq(LinkedHashSet.scala:44)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$Lambda$10/936292831.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractSet.$plus$plus$eq(Set.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.$anonfun$listLeafFiles$2(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$$Lambda$3969/1659440957.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.listLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.refresh0(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.<init>(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createInMemoryFileIndex(DataSource.scala:623)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader$$Lambda$3794/1655878321.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:740)
```

Comment: Yes, everything is Azure.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering (`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`) is due to the attempt to read a large number of Parquet files into a DataFrame all at once, which can cause memory issues. You can use Delta Lake, as it is designed to optimize data lake storage and handling. If your data is stored in Delta Lake format, reading it might be more memory-efficient. You can try reading the data using `format("delta")` instead of `parquet` with the code below:

```
path = "/mnt/files/RAW/"
df = spark.read.format("delta").load(path)  
df.show()
```

This will load the whole Parquet file with partitions, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Bhavani.  As I understand it you can read delta lake files/repos as parquet format and thereby ignoring the meta data, but you cannot read parquet files and repos as delta format since there is no meta data. My own test confirms that:

`You are trying to read from /mnt/datalakegen2/RAW/ConsumptionData/Parquet/V1 using Databricks Delta, but there is no
transaction log present. Check the upstream job to make sure that it is writing
using format("delta") and that you are trying to read from the table base path.`

Comment: Our Stream Analytics job is writing the output as parquet and I believe until recently it was not possible to write outout from eventhub in delta format. Options for serialization format for output data was only JSON, CSV, Avro, and Parquet. Now delta seems to be listed as an option, but not previously.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that information. It's great to hear that Delta format is now listed as an option for output in Stream Analytics jobs. This addition provides more flexibility and capabilities for managing and processing data. Delta format, with its transactional and versioned storage, can be particularly useful for building reliable data pipelines and enabling advanced analytics. It's always good to see platforms evolving to support a wider range of data formats to meet various use cases and requirements.